# How to use linq orderby with a group by

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query below and I will like to orderby t.day. I am new to linq. Where do I put the orderby t.day in this query below? Thanks.

```
        var pracResult = (from t in queryResult
                            group t by new {t.RouteNbr, t.Day,t.NumberOfActionPlans,t.RouteNbrPlusDay}
                            into grp                                     
                            select new
                            {
                                grp.Key.RouteNbr,
                                grp.Key.Day,
                                grp.Key.NumberOfActionPlans,
                                grp.Key.RouteNbrPlusDay,
                            }).ToList();


        //orderby t.Day
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand why you again converted your groups to their keys. If you intend to order your groups you can use,

```
var pracResult = (from t in queryResult
                        group t by new {t.RouteNbr,  t.Day,t.NumberOfActionPlans,t.RouteNbrPlusDay}
                        into grp 
                        orderby grp.Key.Day                                    
                        ).ToList();
```

Else if you want exact equivalent of your code why not just doing this,

```
var pracResult = queryResult.Select(i => new {i.RouteNbr, i.Day, i.NumberOfActionPlans, i.RouteNbrPlusDay})
                        .Distinct() 
                        .OrderBy(k => k.Day)
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
orderby krp.Key.Day
```

after the group clause.

Comment: Why not? What happened? Where did you put it? Do you understand it?

Comment: @SLaks My money says he put the statement after the line that starts with `group` and before the line starting with `into`.

Comment: @Servy: I know.  That's why I asked the last two questions.

Comment: Huh.. I put it at the wrong place. I will correct it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var pracResult = queryResult.GroupBy(t => new {t.RouteNbr, t.Day,t.NumberOfActionPlans,t.RouteNbrPlusDay})
                             .OrderBy(l => l.Key.Day)
                             .Select(grp =>new{ grp.Key.RouteNbr,
                                                 grp.Key.Day,
                                                 grp.Key.NumberOfActionPlans,
                                                 grp.Key.RouteNbrPlusDay}).ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you using `ToLookup` instead of `GroupBy`?  It's needlessly forcing eager execution of the query.